# Why does Python's functools.partial definition use function attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-management

In the [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.partial) example definition, function attributes are used in the returned partial function object:

```
def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

What would be the potential problems if those attributes were removed, like below? Shouldn't Python still keep the references to func, args and keywords as long as newfunc is alive?

```
def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    return newfunc
```

I know that the actual implementation of functools.partial may be completely different, but what if it were implemented this way, why are the attributes necessary?

Comment: The "real" `partial` is a type, not a function. The inner function `newfunc` is taking the place of an *instance* of the type `partial`.

Comment: As the docs say, this function is just a _rough equivalent_ of the actual `partial`

Comment: "but what if it were implemented this way, why are the attributes necessary" This is just to provide a convenient way to access those values, it isn't strictly necessary, in either this implementation nor in the actual implementation (note, these attributes are read-only in the actual partial implementation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any implementation needs the function and its canned arguments stored somewhere. In your two examples you use a closure. When these `partial` implementations return, those values are added to the closure that is returned. In that case, `.func`, `.args` and `.keywords` are redundant. The closure already has them. So, go with option 2.

But python creates a class for this work instead. `.func`, `.args` and `.keywords` are the only copies of the needed data. The class implementation lets you make a partial of a partial in an efficient manner (it combines the arguments of the two partials) and is a bit tidier when building a string display of the object.

But your second closure mechanism is fine, just a different way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Since `partial` is actually a type, it would make more sense to provide an equivalent *class*, rather than turning it into a function.

```
class partial:
    def __init__(self, func, /, *args, **kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.keywords = kwargs

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_keywords = {**self.keywords, **kwargs}
        return self.func(*self.args, *args, **new_keywords)
```

Note that everything that was assigned to the function attributes are now assigned to instance attributes of `self`. When you call an instance of `partial`, you call the original function, with the saved arguments merged with the "immediate" arguments.

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    ...


p = partial(foo, 3, c=9)
p(5)  # Equivalent to foo(3, 5, 9)
```

As to why the documentation uses a function, perhaps it was thought that a nested function would be simpler than explaining what `__call__` does?

---

The function uses function attributes instead of using a closure precisely because the actual implementation of `partial` stores the saved arguments in attributes named `args` and `keywords` as well. They are trying to simulate the real type, after all.

Comment: Well, here's the fallback implementation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b430399d41fa88e9040cd055e55cf9211bf63c61/Lib/functools.py#L276 although note, it is actually implemented in C here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b430399d41fa88e9040cd055e55cf9211bf63c61/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#L42

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm mostly interested in the memory management aspect of the question, not the functools.partial implementation.

Comment: @mindoverflow what memory management aspect, exactly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why wouldn't func, args and keywords be stored as a part of the newfunc without the attributes?

Comment: @mindoverflow I don't understand your question. The values are stored as attributes on the function object, the function object itself (in the example implementation) doesn't use those attributes, it uses a closure over the parameters, but I'm not really seeing what this has to do with memory management or what your query is exactly. Those attributes are part of the `functools.partial` API, [as clearly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects), so that example implementation is including them there.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, you have actually answered it, thanks. So there are two sets of variables here - one is inside the closure, and the attributes are unused. One problem I had is that there doesn't seem to be any documentation on Python's closures.

Comment: @mindoverflow I mean, closures are an implementation detail, but the behavior of free variables in nested scopes is documented.

Comment: Unfortunately, the best documentation is probably in the *original PEPs* that added and elaborated these features, e.g see: https://peps.python.org/pep-0227/ and here: https://peps.python.org/pep-3104/ But again, the behavior of free variables and nested scopes is [definitely documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the function attributes aren't actually necessary in the implementation of a partial function. They are only added because they are required by the [API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects). There are two sets of variables here: one is in the newfunc's closure, and another is in the form of attributes, which are not used by newfunc.

Thanks to [@juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) for clarification.